# how to unit test and get the value of localStorage on react

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, local-storage, sinon

I'm testing out logout function on our react app  and I'm having trouble testing the localStorage. What I want to do is check `if (value === 'logout')` in my unit test so I can have a `expect` assertion that will check if localStorage has the item i'm testing for, this is where I'm having trouble. How can I assert that `if (value === 'logout')` then equals `localStorage.removeItem('id_token')`

Here is the .js snippet I'm testing for

```
  _handleSelectItem = (event, value) => {
    if (value === 'logout') {
      const sharedLogic = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token')
        window.location = '/' // TODO: find a better way to reset the relay cache
      }

      const onSuccess = (response) => {
        sharedLogic()
      }

      const onFailure = (transaction) => {
        var error = transaction.getError() || new Error('Mutation failed.')
        console.error(error)
        sharedLogic()
      }

      this.props.relay.commitUpdate(
        new SignOutUserMutation({
          viewer: this.props.viewer
        }
        ), {onSuccess, onFailure})
    }
  }
```

Here is the .spec.js I wrote that didn't quite do the job that I wanted

```
 if(!global.localStorage) {global.localStorage = {} }
 // if(value === 'logout')
  describe('(Component) AccountManager | Logout ', () => {
    let _component
    let _props
    let value = 'logout'
    // if(value === 'logout')
    beforeEach(() => {
      _props = {
        viewer: {
          email: 'joe@example.com'
        }
      }
      _component = shallowRenderWithProps(_props)
      sinon.spy(global.localStorage, 'getItem')
      sinon.spy(global.localStorage, 'setItem')
      sinon.spy(global.localStorage, 'clear')
    })
    afterEach(() => {
      global.localStorage.getItem.restore()
      global.localStorage.setItem.restore()
      global.localStorage.clear.restore()
    })

it('Should check if Logout work correctly', () => {
  if(value === 'logout');
  console.log(global.localStorage)
  expect(global.localStorage.getItem.withArgs('id_token').calledOnce).is.true;
})
```

Note the test above passes but does not clear the CodeCov error that indicated I should test this. I'm just getting started with react so I appreciate the helping me learn more

Answer (score 0):

```
 if if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem(value) === 'logout') {

 //[do your stuff here]

 }
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code (the two `if` keywords at the start); also, it would make your answer more useful if you added some context, some explanation of how this code solves the questioner's problem.